# Soap getProfiles returns error if device codec is set on H.265

Tags: c++, soap, hevc

I Generated proxy with gSOAP 2.8.123E. Using message included in MediaBindingProxy, I try to retrieve the profile list on a remote Device with GetProfiles message.

If I set the device codec on H.264 everything is fine, but when codec is H.265 I retrieve an error in soap response (sniffing with wireshark I notice that the H.265 profile is properly returned).

```
        bool soap_OK = false;
        MediaBindingProxy   * media;
        AddUsernameTokenDigest(media, NULL, GetUser(), GetPwd(), deltaT); //authentication
        int ret_value = media->GetProfiles(&GetProfiles, GetProfilesResponse);
        if (ret_value == SOAP_OK)
           soap_OK = true; //returns true id H.264, with H.265 returns false
```

Could you help me to fix that? if you need further information please ask in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading documentation on Onvif profile T, H.265 is enabled in "http://www.onvif.org/ver20/media/wsdl" and not in "http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl".

This solve the problem.